# How can I make an event on multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, fselect

Here my html:

```
  <select   id="specific_choice14" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="Shampoing">Shampoing</option>
     <option value="Après Shampoing">Après Shampoing</option>
     <option value="Mask">Mask</option>
     <option value="Oil">Oil</option>
  </select>
```

and here js:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function(){
            $('#specific_choice14').fSelect({
                change: function(event, ui){
                alert('test');
            }
        });
    });       
</script>
```

I want to receive the value of selected items and inserted into database.

Comment: you have a missing ending braces `});` in you code.

Comment: yes but  i just forget to copy and paste all code , the problem is when i select an option the event can not be sets off

Comment: Are you using any external plugin for this?

Comment: I have updated the answer, Did you tried using like that?

Comment: yes i'm using fselect.js for selecting multi choices with search

Answer (score 0):

$('#specific_choice14').change(function() {

```
var select1 = document.getElementById('specific_choice14');
var selected1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < select1.length; i++) {
    if (select1.options[i].selected)            selected1.push(select1.options[i].value);
}


document.getElementById('model_14').value=selected1;


            }





            );
```